# NSInternalInconsistencyException while adding popup

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a popUp in swift and show it when user clicks on a button. 
I am not working with storyboard and the views are created programatically.

```
class CreateNoticePopupViewController: UIViewController {

var popUpView = UIView()

let titleTextField: UITextField = {
    let title = UITextField()
    title.placeholder = "Enter Title"
    title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    title.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24)
    return title
}()

let descriptionTextView: UITextView = {
    let description = UITextView()
    description.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    description.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24)
    description.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return description
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
    self.popUpView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    self.popUpView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    self.popUpView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
}

func showInView(aView: UIView!, animated: Bool)
{
    self.view.addSubview(titleTextField)
    self.view.addSubview(descriptionTextView)
    aView.addSubview(self.view)

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(),
                                                  metrics: nil, views: ["v0": titleTextField]))

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(),
                                                  metrics: nil, views: ["v0": descriptionTextView]))

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-4-[v0]-4-[v1]-4-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(),
                                                  metrics: nil, views: ["v0": titleTextField, "v1": descriptionTextView]))

    if animated
    {
        self.showAnimate()
    }
}

func showAnimate()
{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    });
}

func removeAnimate()
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
        if (finished)
        {
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    });
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

and from the button i am calling this this view Controller like this:

```
let popViewController = CreateNoticePopupViewController(nibName: "PopUpViewController", bundle: nil)
popViewController.showInView(aView: self.view, animated: true)
```

and then it gives me this error. I am following this link
https://blog.typpz.com/2015/01/31/ios-sdk-pop-up-window-in-swift/

This is the error i got 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle with name 'PopUpViewController''

Answer (score 0):

If the VC is created programmatically then instead of this

```
let popViewController = CreateNoticePopupViewController(nibName: "PopUpViewController", bundle: nil)
```

do

```
let popViewController = CreateNoticePopupViewController()
```

Comment: thanks its working now.. i have accepted and upvoted your answer although both of them won't be reflected

Comment: You can't upvote now because it depends on number of reps , right check after 6 mins and it will reflect